# Multiple share extension options

Tags: ios, share-extension

I'm trying to create an ios share extension, so when I try to share an image, my messaging app would show up in the native menu. I'd like to show multiple conversations as possible options to share, or even cover multiple flows like share to chat and share to stories. I see that there are some apps doing that, but I wasn't able to figure out how to handle those. I can create another share extension for stories, but it doesn't seem like a good option + it wouldn't cover dynamic conversations as options case. I'm using a UIViewController, so I can redirect to the app without showing UI. Thanks in advance!